# Docker - FROM requires either one or three arguments

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Getting error:

> Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 1: FROM
> requires either one or three arguments

```
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY src/ .
CMD [ "python", "./server.py" ]
```

Comment: Probably some whitespace noise instead of spaces? / invalid characters

Comment: I cross-checked and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

Your dockerfile is right. Copy again from your post and create another Dockerfile

Comment: Hey, it worked. Wondering how!!